# How many different element numbers does $B$ have?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$|B \cap C| = 0$

$|A \times B| = 3 . |A \times C|$

$|A \times (B \cup C)|  = 24$

How many different element numbers does $B$ have?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Do you have any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: is $3.\vert A\times C\vert$ supposed to be $3 \cdot \vert A \times C \vert$?

Comment: @BenjiAltman Yes, Benji.

Comment: @k.stm I'm trying on it since yesterday.

Comment: @Cargobob Can you show us some of your work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be the cardinality of $A$, $b$ the cardinality of $B$ and $c$ the cardinality of $C$. Note that the sets $B$ and $C$ are disjoint because the cardinality of $B \cap C$ is zero.

Then, we have: cardinality of $A \times B$ as $ab$ and similarly, for $A\times C$. Making use of these facts, we have: $$ab = 3ac \implies b=3c$$ as $a \neq 0$ and $$a(b+c)=24$$ because the cardinality of $B \cup C = |B| + |C| - |B\cap C| = b + c -0 = b+c$.

This leads us to find all possible integer solutions of: $ac = 6\implies (a,c) \equiv (1,6) ; (2,3) ; (3,2) ; (6,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to solve the problem.  You have two equations in three unknowns.  You can do 
$$\begin{align*}
a×b &= 3·(a×c) \\
a×(b+c) &= 24\\b&=3c\\4ac&=24\\ac&=6
\end{align*}$$
But there are a number of ways to factor $6$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*. Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be *positive* integers. From
\begin{align*}
a×b &= 3·(a×c) \\
a×(b+c) &= 24,
\end{align*}
can you figure out what $a$, $b$ and $c$ possibly could be?

Comment: I couldn't get it.